# AngularJs directive function doesn't work when declaring scope

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a directive in which I'm passing an array of data via `scope`. However, when I click on a button with ng-click, the function doesn't work. This is my directive:

```
angular.module('appModule').directive('myDirective', myDirective);
function myDirective() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            myDirective: '=',
        },
        link: function( scope ) {
            scope.enable = function() {
                console.log( 'test' );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And this is my html:

```
<ul my-directive="vm.myData">
    <li ng-repeat="data in vm.myData track by data.id" ng-click="enable( data.id )">{{data.name}}</li>
</ul>
```

When I click on the `li` element, nothing happens. If I remove the scope definition on the `directive`, then I can call the function as expected.

By looking around, I saw that by using the `template` inside the `directive` may solve the problem. But I can't use the `template` inside the `directive` because it may change depending on the location, but the expected final behavior will be the same in multiple views.

Also, I need to access the whole array inside the directive for other purposes.

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: sorry how you call your directive? ...cause my-directive looks like the name oof the isoltaed scope..not the name of the directive

Comment: @federicoscamuzzi I call it using `my-directive`, I'm just using it also to pass the data, instead of creating another attribute. But if, for example, I do it like this: `my-directive data-array="vm.myData"` the result is the same. I edited the question to make it clear =D

Comment: Your directive has its own scope, so if you call `enable` your directive's scope won't know of that

Comment: @devqon but how can I make it work?

Comment: you mixed the directive name and parameter name .

Comment: @AlainIb I don't think that's the case. I'm just assigning the value to the directive instead of creating another attribute. If I create a new attribute to assign the data, the result is the same. And if I remove the scope definition, it will work as is at the moment.

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/8zWou1E9v29PdJFTRMvq?p=preview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

since you declared a scope in the directive you isolated the scope, you have to put an html for the directive with the ng-click

http://plnkr.co/edit/8zWou1E9v29PdJFTRMvq?p=preview

```
  <ul mydirective myparam="myData" >
      <li ng-repeat="data in myData track by data.id" ng-click="enable( data.id )">{{data.name}}</li>
  </ul>
```

this ng-click will call the function defined in parent controller not in mydirective

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
angular.module('appModule').directive('myDirective', myDirective);
    function myDirective() {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            scope: {
                myModel: '=',
            },
            link: function( scope ) {
                scope.enable = function() {
                    console.log( 'test' );
                }
            }
        }
    }

    <ul my-directive my-model="vm.myData">
        <li ng-repeat="data in vm.myData track by data.id" ng-click="enable( data.id )">{{data.name}}</li>
    </ul>
```